# .slideToggle and position:fixed in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm showing and hiding some content with a menu. When the button is clicked, an unordered list and an image with a fixed position is displayed using .slideToggle(). This works, but when multiple elements shown and then hidden, the image stays fixed to where it originally displayed. Is there any way to fix this?

HTML

```
<div class="menuBar">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/DTV30EntertainmentButton.png" id="entertainment"  width="124" height="25" /></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/DTV30ChoiceButton.png" id="choice" width="124" height="25" /></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/DTV30ChoiceXtraButton.png" id="choiceXtra" width="124" height="25" /></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/DTV30ChoiceUltimateButton.png" id="choiceUltimate" width="124" height="25" /></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/DTV30PremierButton.png" id="premier" width="124" height="25" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="packages" id="ent">
<div class="pricePoint"><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/DTV3entertainment_en.png" width="190" height="439" /></div>
    <ul id="entChan">
        <li><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/AandE_logo_4.jpg" height="56" width="70" title="A&E" /><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#959595; padding:20px; font-size:10px;">A&amp;E</span></li>
        <li><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/ABCFamily_logo_4.jpg" height="56" width="70" title="ABC Family" /><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#959595; padding:20px; font-size:10px;">ABCF</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="packages" id="cho">
<div class="pricePoint"><img class="pricePoint" src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/DTV3choice_en.png" width="190" height="439" /></div>
<ul id="choChan">
        <li><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/AandE_logo_4.jpg" height="56" width="70" title="A&E" /><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#959595; padding:20px; font-size:10px;">A&amp;E</span></li>
        <li><img src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/ABCFamily_logo_4.jpg" height="56" width="70" title="ABC Family" /><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#959595; padding:20px; font-size:10px;">ABCF</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menuBar {
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#fff;
    top:55px;
    left:0;
    z-index:11;
}
.pricePoint {
    position:fixed;
    width:190px;
    top:85px;
}
```

JS

```
$('#entertainment').click(function () {
    $("#ent").slideToggle();

});
$('#choice').click(function () {
    $("#cho").slideToggle();

});
```

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the problem, what browser are you using? Works fine in Mozilla Aurora.

Comment: Or are you meaning TV-channels small images that are positioned behind the ad image?

Comment: Oh wow...it looks like it's only doing it in Chrome. Does Chrome respond to fixed positions differently?

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer, so there's nothing to accept yet.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I tried it in chrome I see what you mean. Chrome seems to take the fixed position literally.

If you want more dynamic positions you should use floats.

Try using `float:left` instead. This should fix the problem.

Also, if you bring up the dev tools in chrome while on the site this seems to position the elements properly. Which is strange.

Comment: Thanks for the reply hustlerinc. I tried adding a float:left and it didn't work. You're right though, this is a strange situation.

Comment: Just adding float:left wont fix it, you need to replace the position:fixed, top:55px and left:0px with just float:left, there might be some other issues to fix aswell  after that which can be done with margins etc. Difficult to say without the full code. But this is to my knowledge the best way to achieve what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply hustlerinc. This would definitely work for absolute positioning. But I need the list items to slide under the images. The only way I know how to do that is to fix the position of the images in the window.

Comment: Try it with a wrapping div and fixing the image relative to that div, then you toggle the wrapping div instead (and float left on wrapping divs).

Comment: I'm still having the same error. Thanks for your recommendation though! Chrome is my favorite browser too...how dare it take something so literal haha.